# git commit -aについて

Tags: git

git commit -aは`git add`したファイルのみすべてcommitされるのでしょうか？
git addしていないものがcommitされることは基本ないという認識いいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man git-commit` によると、

> `-a, --all`
>   Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

すなわち、

> 変更か削除されたファイルを自動的にステージングしつつ、新しく追加した（そしてこれまでステージングされていない）ファイルはステージングしないようにします。

ということになります。よって、

### git commit -aはgit addしたファイルのみすべてcommitされるのでしょうか？

いいえ。 `add` していないファイルもステージングされ、commitされますが、新しく追加され、`git-add`されていないファイルはcommitされません。

### git addしていないものがcommitされることは基本ないという認識いいのでしょうか？

はい。

Comment: ‘add していないファイルもステージングされ、commitされますが、新しく追加され、git-addされていないファイルはcommitされません。‘このふたつの差がよく理解できません。addしていないファイルもcommitされてしまうのであれば、結果git commit -aにはaddされていないものも含まれる、とは同義ではないのでしょうか。

Comment: 既にgitの管理下にあるファイルについては、明示的に`git add`しなくても`git commit --all`でcommitされる、ではないでしょうか。 / 新規作成したファイルなどは`git add`しない限り、`git commit --all`ではcommitされない、と私は理解しました。

Comment: @anko さん @cubick氏のご指摘通りで、新しく追加した（新規作成した）ファイルは明示的に `git add` しなければ`git commit -a`してもステージングされず、一方既にgitで管理されているファイルは`git add`せずとも`git commit -a`すると自動的にステージングされる、という意味です。

Answer (score 3):

「git addしたファイル」「git addしていないもの」が指す状態が少し曖昧ですが、 `git commit -a` の意味合いとしては、バージョン管理対象となっているファイルについて、変更分を全て commit する、ということになります。

「git addした **ことがある** ファイル」「**一度も** git addしていないもの」という意味合いであれば認識の通りです。

---

`git commit` コマンド実行時、コミットメッセージ編集画面で `Changes to be committed:` という行以降に今回のコミット対象が出力されますので、今回の commit 操作が想定通りか確認することができます。
( [`-v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--v) オプションを追加して `git commit -av` というようにすると、差分も確認できます。)

あるいは、 `git commit -a` でなく、 代わりに[`git add -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--u) と `git commit` の2コマンドで行えば、 対象を確認してから commit を実行できます。